# Call function from React Component from function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React Component

```
export function sendAlert(msg) {
    showAlert() //How to call in normal function a function from React.Component
}


export class Alert extends React.Component {

  showAlert = () => {
     alert("a")
  };

  render() {
     return (
      <div>
        <h1>Component</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Its possible to call function which call a function from `React.Component`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you *can* do it, but you should probably extract the common function and call it from both places.

You can do it by creating an instance of the component:

```
export function sendAlert(msg) {
    const alert = new Alert();
    alert.showAlert() 
}
```

however, you should extract the code:

```
function commonShowAlert() {
   alert("a");
}

export function sendAlert(msg) {
    commonShowAlert();
}

export class Alert extends React.Component {

    showAlert = () => {
       commonShowAlert();
    };

    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that only if your method is a static one.

You declare your method inside the class as follows :

```
static showAlert() { alert("a"); }
```

and then you can access it outside as CLASSNAME.METHOD_NAME

for example : `Alert.showAlert();`

As @Davin said in his answer, you can declare it outside (that's also my suggestion, cleaner code), but if you have to declare it inside the class, you have the *static* option.

Answer (score 0):

If your method will not using `this`, you can use static method

```
import Alert from '../somewhere';

export function sendAlert(msg) {
    Alert.showAlert() // <<--- use Alert.method() to call a static method
}
```

-

```
export class Alert extends React.Component {

// Make the method to static
static showAlert = () => {
   alert("a")
};

render() {
     return (
         <div>
             <h1>Component</h1>
         </div>
        )
     }
}
```